# Why might an image run differently in Kubernetes than in Docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm experiencing an issue where an image I'm running as part of a Kubernetes deployment is behaving differently from the expected and consistent behavior of the same image run with `docker run <...>`. My understanding of the main purpose of containerizing a project is that it will always run the same way, regardless of the host environment (ignoring the influence of the user and of outside data. Is this wrong?

Without going into too much detail about my specific problem (since I feel the solution may likely be far too specific to be of help to anyone else on SO, and because I've already detailed it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53714029/gunicorn-continually-booting-workers-when-run-in-a-docker-image-on-kubernetes)), I'm curious if someone can detail possible reasons to look into as to why an image might run differently in a Kubernetes environment than locally through Docker.

Comment: First thing I'd suggest looking for is that your `kubectl` client version and server version are within 1 minor version of each other by running `kubectl version`. My versions were off by three. However, fixing the issue did not fix my particular problem

Answer (score 2):

The general answer of why they're different is *resources*, but the real answer is that they should both be identical given identical resources.

Kubernetes uses `docker` for its container runtime, at least in most cases I've seen. There are some other runtimes ([`cri-o`](https://cri-o.io/) and [`rkt`](https://coreos.com/rkt/)) that are less widely adopted, so using those may also contribute to variance in how things work.

On your local `docker` it's pretty easy to mount things like directories (volumes) into the image, and you can populate the directory with some content. Doing the same thing on `k8s` is more difficult, and probably involves more complicated mappings, persistent volumes or an init container.

Running `docker` on your laptop and `k8s` on a server somewhere may give you different hardware resources:

- different amounts of RAM
- different size of hard disk
- different processor features
- different core counts

The last one is most likely what you're seeing, `flask` is probably looking up the core count for both systems and seeing two different values, and so it runs two different thread / worker counts.

Comment: If I'm running both `docker` and `k8s` on my laptop (via `minikube` for `k8s`), would they not have access to the same hardware resources?

Comment: `minikube` runs in a separate VM from `docker`, at least from what I can tell for OSX. You should try the inbuilt k8s from docker if you can, it runs within the same VM as other containers. `docker ps` will show both `docker run` and `k8s` containers side-by-side.